# Char* to string c++ (result not expected)

Tags: c++, printf

i've been 4 hours trying to solve this but i cant. I have this function:

```
  string getRuta(int i, char* buffer, string directorio) {
    int j = 0;
    string nom;
    char s;
    do {
            s = (char) buffer[i];
            nom[j] = s;
            j++;
            i++;
    } while (buffer[i] != 13);
    nom[j] = '\0';
    char *cstr = new char();
    strcpy(cstr, directorio.c_str());
    strcat(cstr, nom.c_str());
    printf("%s\n",cstr);
    string ruta = cstr;
    printf("%s\n",ruta.c_str());
    return ruta; }
```

I cant understand why but at the first print im getting the expected output, but the second one prints something weird. I give you the function inputs, and the prints results.

buffer = "share feo"
directorio = "/home/demian/archredes/"
first print: /home/demian/archredes/feo
second print: /home/demian/archredes/fA

Thanks you!

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that cstr is a pointer to a char. Trying to set a string to a pointer value could definitely cause some wierd output. Maybe take a look at this? http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/41912/

Comment: I've tested with that too, same result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking undefined behavior by modifying a `std::string`'s characters past its end (both `nom[j] =` lines). You should use its `push_back` member function instead, as well as concatenate your strings directly instead of using a `char` buffer.

In addition, you only allocate one character, then `strcpy` way past it... and leak its pointer.

Also, you use a magic number instead of the character constant `\r`.

Here is a corrected (and much simpler) version:

```
string getRuta(int i, char const* buffer, string directorio) {
    string nom;
    char c;
    do {
        c = buffer[i];
        nom.push_back(c);
        i++;
    } while (buffer[i] != '\r');

    string ruta = directorio + nom;
    printf("%s\n",ruta.c_str());
    return ruta;
}
```

Comment: Well, i owe you big time! This fixed it! Thanks, and sorry for my crappy english

Answer (score 2):

You seem to allocate 1 byte of memory for your entire string in the variable `cstr`. Try:

```
char *cstr = new char [directorio.size() + nom.size() + 1];
```

Comment: Same result, i've already trted a lot of things like that... maybe there is another way of implementing this function that im not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing C and C++ in this way isn't a wise thing to do. If you're writing C++ code then avoid C-style code as much as possible. Now in this code:

```
char *cstr = new char();
strcpy(cstr, directorio.c_str());
strcat(cstr, nom.c_str());
```

`cstr` is a pointer to 1 `char`. What you probably meant was allocating an array:

```
char *cstr = new char[directorio.size() + nom.size() - 1];
```

yet you are working with `std::string` objects, so what you should actually do is:

```
std::string ruta = directorio + nom;
```

Comment: With that modifications im getting segment violation. This is so weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate a full array of characters rather than a single character. As is, you are corrupting memory with the strcpy because you allocate 1 character and then copy significantly more data into that space.

Answer (score 0):

Way too much code and a bad mix of C/C++ strings.

A short version:

```
// Precondition: i is a valid index into the buffer.
// Use a const char* (please)
// Use std::size_t (maybe)
string getRuta(std::size_t i, const char* buffer, string directorio) {
    std::size_t k = i;
    // Test for end of string and '\r' == 13
    while(buffer[k] && buffer[k] != '\r') ++k;
    // Append the whole range once, to reduce the number of 
    // possible reallocations:
    return directorio.append(buffer + i, k - i);
}

int main()
{
    const char* buffer = " World\r\n Planet";
    std::cout << getRuta(0, buffer, "Hello") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```